# Two port op amp gyrator circuit examples?

Tags: operational-amplifier, gyrator

I can't seem to find any clear descriptions of how a two port gyrator circuit could be made from op amps. On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyrator), for example, it only gives this one port version describing an op amp based gyrator used to simulate an inductance.

[image: Text]

Comment: Do you see how this (floating inductor) circuit has made? And the answer is a superposition principle. Do you see it?

Comment: When you say "superposition principle", what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: And what is your problem? You are missing "a clear description how...it can be made" - and at the same time you show an opamp-based circuit...Or are you asking for applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watch the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=AEJtajaRj_s&feature=youtu.be&t=289

And here you have a floating inductor (gyrator)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr4FGj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Ah, so this is the classical gyrator then? Well it's certainly a very elegant circuit. Thank you!

Comment: It should be noted that such a "floating" gyrator is required only in a few cases. In most cases - when a floating inductance is to be avoided - we can apply the Bruton transformation and convert inductances in resistors and (grounded) capacitances in grounded active gyrators working as FDNRs.

Answer (score 0):

According to my calculations:
$$ \texttt{if: } R1=R5=\color{red}{R_{g}}\texttt{; } C1=\color{red}{C}\texttt{; } R2=\color{red}{R_L}\texttt{then: } \\
Z_{in} = \frac{
\color{red}{R_L}}
{2}+
\frac{
j\omega \color{red}{R_{g}C}
}
{2}
$$
Therefore, in practice, this circuit cannot be a good floating inductor, since the value of \$ \color{red}{R_L} \$ will be close to \$ \color{red}{R_{g}C} \$, unless the values of \$ \color{red}{R_{g}} \$ and \$ \color{red}{C} \$ are unreasonably high, making the circuit unfeasible for practical applications.
In addition to the calculations, I simulated this circuit on PSpice (OrCAD) and physically built the circuit and is really no way this circuit can function as a good floating inductor.